# Vuex: Unknown Getter in a Feature-Scoped Module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm using Vuex stores in a "feature-scope structure" for the first time and have been having difficulties tracing why I am getting a `[vuex] unknown getter: $_kp/kp` - (Vue/Vuex isn't throwing much of a bone with this other than just the quoted error).

**UPDATE**: I turned on `store.subscribeAction()` to see if that give up any more info. Here is the printed log (I'm not seeing any this useful but hopefully it helps you).

> Action Type:  $_kp/getKpIndex
>
> Action Payload:  undefined
>
> Current State:  {**ob**: Observer} $_kp: Object kp: "2" //<- That is what I'm trying to get - "2"!

**UPDATE-2:** I'm using Vues Inspector now as well and it shows the following:

```
| State
| - $_kp: object
  | - kp: "3"

| Mutation
| - payload: "3"
| - type: "$_kp/KP_DATA_UPDATED"
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated and I hope this can be useful for who sets their stores in this manner.

**SomeElement.vue:**

```html
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
import store from '../_store';

export default {
  name  : 'KpIndexElement',
  parent: 'AVWX',

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      kp: '$_kp/kp', //<-- HERE?
    }),
  },

  created() {
    const STORE_KEY = '$_kp';
    if (!(STORE_KEY in this.$store._modules.root._children)) {//<= I think there is an issue with this too
      this.$store.registerModule(STORE_KEY, store);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('$_kp/getKpIndex');
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <p><strong>Kp: </strong>{{ kp }}</p>
</template>
```

**The Store `index.js`**

```js
import actions      from './actions';
import getters      from './getters';
import mutations    from './mutations';

var state = {
    kp: '',
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
};
```

**actions.js:**

```js
import api from '../_api/server';

const getKpIndex = (context) => {
  api.fetchKpData
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('fetch response: ' + response)
    context.commit('KP_DATA_UPDATED', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  })
}

export default {
  getKpIndex,
}
```

**mutations.js**

```js
const KP_DATA_UPDATED = (state, kp) => {
  state.kp = kp;
}

export default {
  KP_DATA_UPDATED,
}
```

**...and finally the `getters.js`**

```js
const kp = state => state.kp;

export {
  kp,
};
```

Comment: In your `getters.js`, what is `kp`? you should be `export { products }`, or define `const kp = state => state.kp`, or `export { kp: products}`

Comment: LOL - I must have copied something else when I submitted the question. See: edit.

Comment: Maybe you can try `beforeCreate` instead of `created`. Also, I'm not sure if `mapGetters` is called before you actually `registerModule`. Maybe you can create `computed` for that: `kp() { return this.$store['$_kp'].kp }`

Comment: Just pass an array: 
`...mapGetters(['kp']),`

Comment: I'm having no luck hear (..or I am just not seeing it). Tried `beforeEach` and replacing the `mapGetters` with the `kp()` <- that  throws "Cannot read property 'kp' of undefined". Could you throw up some code that I can play with? Thnx.

Comment: I added the `store.subscribeAction()` to see if it logs any more helpful info. Please see "UPDATE:" above. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `mapGetters` when using namespaces is as follows :

```
...mapGetters('namespace', [
    'getter1',
    'getter2',
    ... // Other getters 
])
```

In your case :

```
...mapGetters('$_kp', [
    'kp'
])
```

The first argument is the namespace, the second the payload containing the getters you want to use.

Also, as noted in the comments by @Ijubadr, I'm not sure `mapGetters` is evaluated after you registered your `store` module. To work around that, you might have to drop the use of `mapGetters` and declare your `STORE_KEY` as a data, then define a computed getter using `STORE_KEY` in its definition (I renamed it `storeKey` in the example below since this is no longer a constant):

```js
computed: mapState('$_kp',{
  kpIndex: 'kp'
}),

created() {
  this.storeKey = '$_kp';
  if (!(this.storeKey in this.$store._modules.root._children)) {
    this.$store.registerModule(this.storeKey, store);
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch('$_kp/getKpIndex');
}
```

Comment: `this.storeKey = '$_kp';` in your answer literally returns "$_kp"; not the value of the object - Which should be "2".  Any other ideas? Thnx.

Comment: `this.storeKey` is supposed to return `'$_kp'`. Your getter should be access with `this.myKpGetter`. If `this.myKpGetter` returns `'$_kp'`, please post a sample of your implementation, because this should not be possible.

Comment: (`this.storeKey` basically juste replaces `STORE_KEY` in your example, nothing more. I just needed it to be accessible from `myKpGetter` )

Comment: Not sure why but using `mapState()` works over `mapGetter()`. So, `computed: mapState('$_kp',{ kp: 'kp'}),` was the way to go. I'm accepting your answer because of the second code block is what got me there. Thnx!

Comment: Thank you. There is definitely something unclear to me here, but glad it worked out for you !

Comment: "There is definitely something unclear to me here" -> DITTO! LOL